# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

Ive been using this project with out a problem and now all of a sudden I keep getting this error and it won't show my notes when I click on the my notes section. What do I have to do for it to go away. The backend is up and running and I can see the static data but it wont show on the app

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import React from 'react'
import { Drawer } from '@mui/material'
import { Typography } from '@mui/material'
import List from '@mui/material/List'
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem'
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon'
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText'
import { AddCircleOutlineOutlined, SubjectOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar'
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar'
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors'


const drawerWidth = 240 // 500 - subtract this number from 

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
    return{
    page: {
        background: '#E5E4E2',
        width: '100%',
        padding: theme.spacing(3)
    },
    drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth
    },
    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth
    },
    root: {
        display: 'flex' //places the drawer side by side with the page content
    },
    active: {
        background: '#E5E4E2'
    },
    // title:{
    //     padding: theme.spacing(13),
    //     alignItems: 'center'
    // },
    
}})

export default function Layout({ children }) {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const history = useHistory()
    const location = useLocation()

    const menuItems = [
        {
            text: 'My Projects',
            icon: <SubjectOutlined color="secondary" />,
            path: '/'
        },
        {
            text: 'Create Project',
            icon: <AddCircleOutlineOutlined color="secondary" />,
            path: '/create'
        }
    ]

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        {/* side drawer */}
        <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant='permanent' //Lets MUI know we want it on the page permanently 
        anchor="left" // position of drawer
        classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper}}
        >
            <div>
                <Typography variant="h5" sx={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    Projects
                </Typography>
            </div>

       {/* List / Links */}
       <List>
        {menuItems.map(item => (
            <div className={location.pathname == item.path ? classes.active : null}>
            <ListItem key={item.text} button onClick={() => history.push(item.path)}>
                <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
            </ListItem>
            </div>
        ))}
       </List>
        </Drawer>


        <div className={classes.page}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar}></div>
            {children}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7jY7.png)

Comment: The key warning and your items not showing up are two mostly unrelated issues. You can remove the warning by... adding a key attribute to the main <div> you're .map()ping, like `key={item.text}` for instance. Just move it up from the <ListItem> element.

Comment: per usual great answer Chris!! This helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

I'm sorry, of course, you should just move key to the parent div. I didn't notice it. Chris who answered in the comments is right and my answer was not needed. I rewrote the answer.

To have an unique key use index in map or like you did item.text if text is unique for each element in map.

```
menuItems.map((item,index) =>
```

The idea is that map has to contain unique key for each element.
In result we have:

```
<div key={item.text} className={location.pathname == item.path ? classes.active : null}>
```

or

```
<div key={index} className={location.pathname == item.path ? classes.active : null}>
```

And you need to remove key from the List.

Hope this helps! Regards,

Comment: Glad to hear that it was helpful! 
I think it is better to ask a question here at stackoverflow, just send a link to a new question. 
Your gitgub is an open project?

Comment: I will do If and when im stuck again. Nice to meet someone willing to help. Much appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/Orelso/Project-notes For some reason whenever I delete the notes they come back after I refresh the page. Idk what I did because it wasn't doing that before. @choose-goose

Comment: I have edited my answer. First one was wrong. 
About GitHub, I have installed your repository locally but I have some version conflicts of React Router Dom. So no chance to launch it fast and unfortuntely no time to find the reason of these errors. May be you can ask the question here or create a new question? I will definitely look at it. @suomimies

Comment: Could you answer this for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73499526/how-can-i-keep-the-check-boxes-checked-after-refresh?noredirect=1#comment129794532_73499526.   @ChooseGoose