# How can I keep the check-boxes checked after refresh?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

What do I need to add to this code to have the checkboxes stay checked even after I refresh the page? A code sample or an explanation would be appreciated  Here is the fullcode to the project : https://github.com/Orelso/Project-notes

If you need me to add any other part of the code let me know

```js
import React from "react";
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import { FormControlLabel, FormGroup, IconButton, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { DeleteOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { blue } from "@mui/material/colors";


const theme = createTheme ({
    palette: {
        category: {
            color: blue
        }
    }
})

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    test: {
        border: (note) => {
            if (note.category == 'HTML/CSS') {
                return '2px solid blue' 
            } else if (note.category == 'Javascript') {
                return '2px solid green'
            } else if (note.category == "Javascript/React") {
                return '2px solid yellow'
            }else if (note.category == 'MUI') {
                return '2px solid red'
            }
        }
    },
})



export default function NoteCard({ note, handleDelete }) {
    const classes = useStyles(note)

    
    return (
        <div>
            <Card elevation={10} className={classes.test}>
                <CardHeader 
                    action={ // 200
                        <IconButton onClick={() => handleDelete(note.id)}> 
                            <DeleteOutlined />
                        </IconButton>
                    }
                    title={<span style={{fontFamily: "monospace", color: "#000000"}}>{note.title}</span>}
                    subheader={<span style={{fontFamily: "Courier New", color: "#000000"}}>{note.category}</span>}                    />
                <CardContent>
                    <FormGroup>
                    <FormControlLabel sx={{color: '#000000'}} control={<Checkbox color="warning"  />} label={note.details} />
                    <FormControlLabel sx={{color: '#555555'}} control={<Checkbox  />} label={note.details2} />
                    <FormControlLabel sx={{color: '#000000'}} control={<Checkbox  />} label={note.details3} />
                    <FormControlLabel sx={{color: '#555555'}} control={<Checkbox  />} label={note.details4} />

                    </FormGroup>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload current page without losing any form data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data)

Comment: not sure that does it. Can you provide me a coe sample?

Comment: @therealslim, if you check the link that Stern sent, you will see code samples there

Comment: I see them but i dont know how to apply them to my code

Answer (score 2):

you can use redux persist to save your data in the local storge the only way to save data or get that data from back-end from rest API

Comment: can you share a code sample?

Comment: have you worked with redux so far ?

Comment: not really :((.

Comment: it's hard to explain every detail I suggest you read the quick start document then if you can't solve the problem, comment in this post then I help you :D or ask question in redux communtiy

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data entered by the user using a [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp).

```
localStorage.setItem("keyname", "valueName");
```

After that, in the component where you need to get this saved data, you access the storage.

```
localStorage.getItem("keyname");
```

So in your case you need first to setItem to Local Storage after user change something. Then update the state. Using useEffect you can getItem from localstorage each time the component it loaded.

```
var style,classes;
const [mystate,setMystate] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
    style = localStorage.getItem(keyname);
    classes = setMystate(style);
},[]);
```

After that you can access this variable for your purposes. But you need to update this state every time user change something related to it.

If you need the data of these checkboxes throughout the application, and not just in one component, then you need to use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or redux. In general, you can access the store in each component, but usually we make a global context and access it for global variables. For example, the global style of the application or checking if the user is logged in or not.

Hope this helps! Regards,